# Targeting a specific CSS transform with transition

Tags: css

Is there a way to target a specific CSS Transform property (such as `Rotate()`, `Scale()`, `TranslateX()`) with the Transition property? Something along the lines of:

```
transition: 200ms transform-Rotate, 500ms transform-TranslateX;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The [CSS transition spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-css3-transitions-20130212/#transition-property-property) states that only single CSS properties can be used in the `transition-property` field. `transform` is a CSS property. `Rotate()`, `Scale()`, etc, are `transform` functions, not CSS properties.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I'll just do a wrapper for each property I need to be animated separately. It should only be 2 so it's not too bad.